# how do i know the performance of each categorical features

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

I am building a model using logistic regression in my training data i have three features one feature is categorical feature(ex color: blue, red, green ).I converted into dummy variable and build the model.i want to know the performance of each type green red blue instead of whole

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the feature where the categorical data is stored is in the first column thus index `0`. You can extract the data associated with each category from `X_test` as

```
col = 0
for i in set(X_test[:,col]):
    ixs = X_test[:,col] == i
    print('Category ' + str(i) + ': ') 
    print(metrics.accuracy_score(X_test[ixs], y_test[ixs]))
```

This will give you the accuracy for each category in the 1st column.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for you reply. I got this error                                 
Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and binary targets

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code and a sample of your data please?

Comment: ([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., -0.30519614,
        -0.66772746,  0.19414677]]) . x is of 43 columns long and 1st 41 columns belong to categorical feature they are converted into 0 and 1 the y is just 1 column which contains zeros and 1s